# WolframAlpha syntax - evaluate series at a point

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am looking for syntax for WolframAlpha, which would evaluate a series at a given point. My goal is to have a sheet of practice exercises with links to solutions in WolframAlpha.

Example problem: *Approximate the value of
$\sqrt{102}$
using Taylor series of appropriate function at appropriate point of 2nd order.*

The solution on paper is straightforward: calculate a Taylor series of 2nd order of
$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$
at
$x_0=100$
and plug in
$x=102$
. In WolframAlpha, I can get the Taylor series with a query such as "Taylor series of sqrt(x) at x=100 to order 2". I can also evaluate any expression via "evaluate x^2+2x+1 at x=102". Is there any way to evaluate the series at a given point?

I tried many combinations of verbose commands as well as direct Mathematica inputs, but nothing seems to work. I have a feeling it has something to do with the error term.

Comment: The Mathematica command that will get you this is `Normal[Series[Sqrt[x], {x, 100, 2}]] /. {x -> 102}` 
however I'm not sure you can get Wolfram Alpha to parse it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a hacky solution, but you can nest "`Limit`", `Sum`, and `SeriesCoefficient` to produce what you want, although WA is very particular about the syntax ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BSeriesCoefficient%5BSqrt%5B100%2Bx%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D+*+x%5En%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+2%7D%5D+as+x-%3E2.0)):

```
Sum[SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[100+x], {x, 0, n}] * x^n, {n, 0, 2}] as x->2.0
                                                            ↑
                                                          degree
```

Neither using the symbol `Limit` nor natural language, e.g. `Limit[Sum[...], x->2.0]` / `limit Sum[...] as x->2.0`, returned any useful results. Replace `2.0` with `2` if an exact result is desired.

I'm including a screenshot of the output for posterity:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I never expected such an old question to be answered. I am actually impressed that this input also returns the Taylor series (labeled as such). Also, I was unaware of the 2.0 vs 2 trick, I shall use it in the future.

Comment: You're welcome! Though just to be clear, the displayed "Series expansion at $x=2$" is literally the series expansion of the limand at $x=2$, i.e. the Taylor series of the [degree-$2$ Taylor series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BSeriesCoefficient%5BSqrt%5B100%2Bx%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D+*+x%5En%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+2%7D%5D). It's not particularly useful in its given form, but it is identical to the $2^{\rm nd}$-order approximation that the prompt is having us use.